# How can I best describe to others a sequence of actions from an application?

Tags: gui-design, guidelines

I want to be able to explain pepole vie email or posts here at UX stack exchage what is my current sequance of action performed in my application .. e.g. creating a division in my application.

[image]

Is there a better way to explain a sequence of such actions ?
For now i can surly tell that there is some missing information e.g clicks.
maybe there a way to create online screen capture that can be easily shared ?

Answer (score 1):

To explain the sequence of actions and events, **sequence diagrams** are (unsurprisingly) quite useful.

They are usually able to communicate fairly complicated sequences with conditions, branches and loops. They do not, however, show the actual design but might refer to it through annotations and such. While this might be overkill for your (fairly simple) case, these diagrams scale quite well as interactions grow in complexity.

[PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/sequence.html) is a nice tool with a fairly intuitive syntax we frequently use to create them. A text based syntax works extremely well with common development tools such as version control.

Example Sequence Diagram:

[image: Example Sequence Diagram]

*from the [PlantUML website](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/sequence.html)*

Comment: I know about sequence diagrams. As you mentioned the main disadvantage of using them is hat it would not show the UI, and in some cases i could not express well the user experience  without the UI design. I was thinking mor of a tool that could create a sires of screenshots with an easy tool ...